# В AspNet 5 не работат ModelBinders

Tags: asp.net-mvc

AspNet 5. Добавил в Startup.cs

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

...

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{...

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Cart), new CartModelBinder());
```

Ошибка :

> ModelBinders не существует в текущем контексте

```
System.Web.Mvc:
```

DNX 4.5 -доступно

DNX 5 - нет данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelBinders, как и все остальное в новом MVC, настраиваются через добавление опций:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinders.Add(...);
    });
}
```

Статической точки для настройки `ModelBinders` больше нет.